# c++ doubles and floats, how to get around the ugly truth

Tags: c++, double, decimal, precision

```
double f1 = 0.00000001;
double f2 =  7.00000001;
double f3 = -7.00000000;
double sum = f2 + f3;
bool shouldBeTrue = sum == f1;
```

shouldBeTrue is false using VS C++ 2015/2017

```
float f1 = 0.00001;
float f2 = 7.00001;
float f3 = -7.00000;
float sum = f2 + f3;
bool shouldBeTrue = sum == f1;
```

shouldBeTrue is false using VS C++ 2015/2017

how to implement this in c++ so I can store the values written in the code and not the approximations? any new types or library available?
 (e.g. like decimal type in c#)

Comment: Use hexadecimal floating point, instead of decimal approximations which will be converted to hexadecimal floating point.

Comment: You can't store the values written in the code. They are not valid float/double values.

Comment: Just change the name of that Boolean to `mightBeTrue`.

Comment: @immibis, that is not true, c# does it, c++ should be able to do it too.

Comment: @Pete Beker, good one! :)

Comment: C# doesn't do it.

Comment: @immibis please try before you speak, c# has a way to do it

            decimal f1 = 0.00000001M;
            decimal f2 = 7.00000001M;
            decimal f3 = -7.00000000M;
            decimal sum = f2 + f3;
            bool shouldBeTrue = sum == f1;

Comment: @Ovi-WanKenobi decimal isn't double or float...

Comment: @immibis, I think you are missing the point, c# has a way for me as a dev to get exactly the same value I write/expect, whereas c++ seems it doesn't, and I am asking for a similar way in c++, a library, etc.

Comment: So you are asking how to get a decimal type in C++. Just say that...

Comment: yes, I added a note in the initial description. thanks